# Stopping openvswitch-switch service breaks netplan

Tags: apt, 22.04, netplan

I upgraded my system to Jammy Jellyfish 22.04 last week.
Now when I try to `systemctl stop openvswitch-switch` the command stopes openvswitch (expected). But in doing so it breaks netplan.

So with openvswitch stopped, if I try to make a change to netplan and do a `sudo netplan apply` I get this error:

```
# sudo netplan apply
ovs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/netplan", line 23, in <module>
    netplan.main()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py", line 50, in main
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 247, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 61, in run
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 247, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 167, in command_apply
    NetplanApply.process_ovs_cleanup(config_manager, old_files_ovs, restart_ovs, exit_on_error)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 394, in process_ovs_cleanup
    apply_ovs_cleanup(config_manager, ovs_old, ovs_current)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/ovs.py", line 138, in apply_ovs_cleanup
    out = subprocess.check_output([OPENVSWITCH_OVS_VSCTL, '--columns=name,external-ids',
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/ovs-vsctl', '--columns=name,external-ids', '-f', 'csv', '-d', 'bare', '--no-headings', 'list', 'Port']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Here are the versions installed (I did dpdk installed)

```
# sudo apt list | grep openvswitch

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

neutron-openvswitch-agent/jammy-updates 2:20.2.0-0ubuntu1 all
openvswitch-common/jammy-updates,now 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openvswitch-dbg/jammy-updates 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
openvswitch-doc/jammy-updates 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 all
openvswitch-ipsec/jammy-updates 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
openvswitch-pki/jammy-updates 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 all
openvswitch-source/jammy-updates 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 all
openvswitch-switch-dpdk/jammy-updates,now 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installed]
openvswitch-switch/jammy-updates,now 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openvswitch-test/jammy-updates 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 all
openvswitch-testcontroller/jammy-updates 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
openvswitch-vtep/jammy-updates 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64
python3-openvswitch/jammy-updates,now 2.17.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 all [installed,automatic]
```

Anyone know how to fix netplan so it keeps working when openvswitch it stopped?

Comment: Thanks for reporting it. Do you have any netplan configuration in /etc/netplan related to openvswitch? If you are not using netplan to manage openvswitch configuration, removing it from your yaml files should be a workaround for now. I will create a bug report for it.

Comment: I do not manage open switch from netplan at all. Did you want me to share my netplan configuration? If so I can update my post.